# Display an image triggered from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a directory of images that I would like to display based upon input from a datepicker jquery calendar. The filename format of the images is: YYMMDD_file.png. E.g., 180303_image.png

I'd like to display the proper image of the day, triggered by a click on the corresponding jquery calendar (https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), with a range of only the previous 3 months. For the datepicker, I so far have for jquery and html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {     
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate = date.getDate();
    var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar123').datepicker({
        minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth-3, currentDate),
        maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
    });
});</script>
<div style="font-weight: bold;">Previous 3 months</div>
<div id="calendar123"></div>
```

How can I then choose the date from datepicker and display my corresponding image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `onSelect` notification from the `datepicker` to get the currently selected date:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
            var currentDate = date.getDate();
            var currentYear = date.getFullYear();
            //Set the relative path to the images folder.
            var imagePath = "../images/";

            $('#calendar123').datepicker({
                minDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth - 3, currentDate),
                maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate),
                onSelect: function (theDate) {
                    // Convert the date string to a Date
                    var selectedDate = new Date(theDate);
                    var imageName = "";
                    var year = selectedDate.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2); // Get last two digits.
                    var month = ("0" + (selectedDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // Added 1 as the month value is zero indexed.
                    var day = ("0" + selectedDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
                    imageName = year + month + day + "_image.png";    
                    $("#myImage").attr('src', imagePath + imageName);
                }
            });
        });</script>

    <div style="font-weight: bold;">Previous 3 months</div>
    <div id="calendar123"></div>
    <img id="myImage">
```

Comment: Can you provide the code to display the image as in the original question? I will then be able to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Updated as requested, also using your naming convention.

Comment: Adding 1 to month causes:<img id="myImage" src="180211_image.png"> to go to <img id="myImage" src="182111_imagepng">

Comment: I fixed this by: 

var month = selectedDate.getMonth() + 1;
month = ("0" + month);